# Strange angular version resolving bug with bower install

Tags: angularjs, bower

I'm trying to update my angular version, and I think bower went just mad.

My deps :

```
    "dependencies": {
    "underscore":"*",
    "momentjs":"~2.2.1",
    "bootstrap": "~3.0.0",
    "jquery": "~1.9.1",
    "jquery.cookie": "*",
    "jquery-ui": "~1.10.3",
    "jquery-file-upload": "*",
    "angular": "~1.2.0-rc.2",
    "angular-route": "~1.2.0-rc.2",
    "angular-resource": "~1.2.0-rc.2",
    "angular-animate": "~1.2.0-rc.2",
    "angular-cookies": "~1.2.0-rc.2",
    "angular-i18n": "~1.2.0-rc.2",
    "angular-bootstrap" : "*",
    "ng-grid": "*",
    "highcharts": "*",
    "highcharts-ng": "*"
},

"devDependencies": {
    "angular-mocks": "~1.2.0-rc.2",
    "angular-scenario": "~1.2.0-rc.2"
}
```

the important thing here is : all angular modules are version 1.2.0-rc.2

But when doing

```
bower install
```

here is the result :

```
Unable to find a suitable version for angular, please choose one:
1) angular#1.0.8 which resolved to 1.0.8 and has angular-scenario#1.2.0-rc.2 as dependants
2) angular#1.2.0-rc.2 which resolved to 1.2.0-rc.2 and has angular-animate#1.2.0-rc.2, angular-cookies#1.2.0-rc.2, angular-mocks#1.2.0-rc.2, angular-resource#1.2.0-rc.2, angular-route#1.2.0-rc.2, angular-scenario#1.2.0-rc.2 as dependants
3) angular#~1.2.0-rc.2 which resolved to 1.2.0-rc.2 and has tael-web as dependants
4) angular#>=1 which resolved to 1.2.0-rc.2 and has angular-bootstrap#0.6.0 as dependants
5) angular#>=1.0.4 which resolved to 1.2.0-rc.2 and has highcharts-ng#0.0.2 as dependants
```

bower seems to think that angular-scenario 1.2.0-rc2 requires angular 1.0.8 ... ???

which is actually just false : https://github.com/angular/bower-angular-scenario/tree/v1.2.0-rc.2

bower.json :

```
{
  "name": "angular-scenario",
  "version": "1.2.0-rc.2",
  "main": "./angular-scenario.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "1.2.0-rc.2"
  }
}
```

What I am missing here ? What can I do to resolve this ? To be clear : I dont want to use the interactive conflict resolving method, because this is appening on a remote CI. I just want to underscore how the *** assume angular scenario 1.2.0-rc2 as angular 1.0.8 as dependency...

thanks

Comment: I have a similar config and I get: `angular#~1.2.0-rc.2 which resolved to 1.2.0-rc.2 and has myproject as dependants`. Even more weird.

Comment: in this case, the library in question is ember. I can press the number 2 and bower will install the 2nd option, ember#1.5.1.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Try adding this section to your bower.json:

```
"dependencies": {
  ...
},
"resolutions":{
  "angular": "1.2.0-rc.2"
}
```

Note: angular version in resolutions as same as version in dependencies.

Comment: bower local cache was actually crazy. Juste fixing resolutions was the right thing to work around. (accepting answer one year later, but still !)

Answer (score 8):

I got the same problem with the latest bower version.

You can just do as the bower output prompts: **`Prefix the choice with ! to persist it to bower.json`** to choose one from the options provided. Then your `bower.json` will be updated with an additional **`"resolutions": { ...  }`** block then the problem will be solved.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

`"angular": "~1.2.0-rc.2"`

Try:

`"angular": "=1.2.0-rc.2"`

Might not be the right way to do it however but it solved a similar issue in my project.

Comment: Do you have an up-to-date version of bower? I just tried with your file and everything resolved fine.