# What does Bower mean when it says "unable to find a suitable version"?

Tags: angularjs, bower

What does it mean when it says "unable to find a suitable version for angular"? In my bower.json I have specified 1.2.6 as the angular version. Why am I being given 6 choices here, 5 of which may cause my project to stop working?

```
Unable to find a suitable version for angular, please choose one:
    1) angular#1.2.6 which resolved to 1.2.6 and is required by angular-scenario#1.2.6 
    2) angular#1.2.15 which resolved to 1.2.15 and is required by angled-horizon 
    3) angular#1.2.16 which resolved to 1.2.16 and is required by angular-animate#1.2.16 
    4) angular#>= 1.0.2 which resolved to 1.2.16 and is required by angular-ui-utils#0.1.1 
    5) angular#>=1 which resolved to 1.2.16 and is required by angular-bootstrap#0.10.0 
    6) angular#~1.2.10 which resolved to 1.2.16 and is required by angular-strap#2.0.1
```

Also, what happens if I use `!` to persist it to bower.json?

Here is my bower.json if it helps:

```
{
  "name": "angled-horizon",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "1.2.15",
    "json3": "3.2.6",
    "es5-shim": "2.1.0",
    "jquery": "1.10.2",
    "sass-bootstrap": "3.0.2",
    "angular-resource": "1.2.6",
    "angular-cookies": "1.2.6",
    "angular-sanitize": "1.2.6",
    "angular-route": "1.2.6",
    "angular-ui-utils": "0.1.1",
    "angular-animate": "1.2.6",
    "angular-bootstrap": "0.10.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "angular-mocks": "1.2.6",
    "angular-scenario": "1.2.6",
    "angular-ui-utils": "0.1.1"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "angular": "1.2.15"
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you ever manage to find an answer to your question?

Comment: You can find the solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18922511/strange-angular-version-resolving-bug-with-bower-install. This solved it for me.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I found this [answer](https://github.com/bower/bower/issues/866) in the internet.

You can have a look on it, they are suggesting to add *resolution*

```
"resolutions": {
    "angular": "1.2.0-rc.2"
  }
```