# Bower Error: Unable to find suitable version for angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, bower

I'm using bower in Visual Studio 2012 and I could migrate most JS/CSS libraries from NUGET to Bower but there's a few I cannot update, getting the same error on all. I'm new to bower so there might be something I'm missing maybe? I did tried to add the resolutions to my bower.json but still give me similar errors.

My bower.json

```
{
  "name": "Web",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "ignore": [
    "**/.*",
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components",
    "test",
    "tests"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "~1.3.11",
    "bootstrap": "~3.3.2",
    "jqueryui": "~1.11.2",
    "requirejs": "~2.1.15",
    "fontawesome": "~4.3.0",
    "angular-smart-table": "~1.4.9",
    "angularjs-toaster": "~0.4.10",
    "angular-local-storage": "~0.1.5",
    "angular-translate": "~2.5.2",
    "angular-cookies": "~1.3.11",
    "angular-translate-loader-static-files": "~2.5.2",
    "angular-loading-bar": "~0.6.0",
    "oclazyload": "~0.5.2"
  }
}
```

This is for angular-translate-storage-cookie

```
PM> bower install angular-translate-storage-cookie -save
bower angular-translate-storage-cookie#*           cached git://github.com/PascalPrecht/bower-angular-translate-storage-cookie.git#2.5.2
bower angular-translate-storage-cookie#*         validate 2.5.2 against git://github.com/PascalPrecht/bower-angular-translate-storage-cookie.git#*
bower angular-cookies#~1.2.26                      cached git://github.com/angular/bower-angular-cookies.git#1.2.28
bower angular-cookies#~1.2.26                    validate 1.2.28 against git://github.com/angular/bower-angular-cookies.git#~1.2.26
bower angular#1.2.28                               cached git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1.2.28
bower angular#1.2.28                             validate 1.2.28 against git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1.2.28
bower angular#*                                    cached git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1.3.11
bower : bower                                           ECONFLICT Unable to find suitable version for angular
At line:1 char:1
+ bower install angular-translate-storage-cookie -save
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (bower          ...ion for angular:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
```

angular-translate-storage-local

```
PM> bower install angular-translate-storage-local -save
bower angular-translate-storage-local#*           cached git://github.com/PascalPrecht/bower-angular-translate-storage-local.git#2.5.2
bower angular-translate-storage-local#*         validate 2.5.2 against git://github.com/PascalPrecht/bower-angular-translate-storage-local.git#*
bower angular-translate-storage-cookie#~2.5.2     cached git://github.com/PascalPrecht/bower-angular-translate-storage-cookie.git#2.5.2
bower angular-translate-storage-cookie#~2.5.2   validate 2.5.2 against git://github.com/PascalPrecht/bower-angular-translate-storage-cookie.git#~2.5.2
bower angular-cookies#~1.2.26                     cached git://github.com/angular/bower-angular-cookies.git#1.2.28
bower angular-cookies#~1.2.26                   validate 1.2.28 against git://github.com/angular/bower-angular-cookies.git#~1.2.26
bower angular#1.2.28                              cached git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1.2.28
bower angular#1.2.28                            validate 1.2.28 against git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1.2.28
bower angular#*                                   cached git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1.3.11
bower angular#*                                 validate 1.3.11 against git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#*
bower : bower                                          ECONFLICT Unable to find suitable version for angular
At line:1 char:1
+ bower install angular-translate-storage-local -save
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (bower          ...ion for angular:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
```

angular-bootstrap

```
PM> bower install angular-bootstrap -save
bower angular-bootstrap#*       cached git://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap-bower.git#0.12.0
bower angular-bootstrap#*     validate 0.12.0 against git://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap-bower.git#*
bower angular#>=1 <1.3.0        cached git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1.2.28
bower angular#>=1 <1.3.0      validate 1.2.28 against git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#>=1 <1.3.0
bower angular#*                 cached git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1.3.11
bower : bower                        ECONFLICT Unable to find suitable version for angular
At line:1 char:1
+ bower install angular-bootstrap -save
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (bower          ...ion for angular:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
```

angularAMD

```
PM> bower install angularAMD -save
bower angularAMD#*              cached git://github.com/marcoslin/bower-angularAMD.git#0.2.1
bower angularAMD#*            validate 0.2.1 against git://github.com/marcoslin/bower-angularAMD.git#*
bower angular#~1.2.0            cached git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1.2.28
bower angular#~1.2.0          validate 1.2.28 against git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#~1.2.0
bower angular#*                 cached git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1.3.11
bower : bower                        ECONFLICT Unable to find suitable version for angular
At line:1 char:1
+ bower install angularAMD -save
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (bower          ...ion for angular:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
```

Comment: add this to bower.cc - "ignoredDependencies": ["angular"]

Answer (score 3):

You should provide version with each command :-

**UPDATE with compatible version**

```
  bower install angular-bootstrap#0.1.0 --save
  bower install angularAMD#0.0.1 --save
    ..etc
```

Comment: Triyin your commands give me the error No tag found that was able to satisfy 1.3.11. (I guess you mean the version of the specific library instead of the angular library but if I put the latest version of angularAMD for eample I give same issue)

Comment: Yes  version of currently available lib with compatible version of angular js.

Comment: That means I need to downgrade angular library, I don't really want to do that because I use the new features on 1.3. The only solution I found around is manually maintain those libraries but would like to find another solution inside bower.

Comment: no need for downgrade you can use 
"resolutions": {
    "angular": "~1.3.x"
  }                               
           
Refer:-
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18922511/strange-angular-version-resolving-bug-with-bower-install

Comment: Sorry but as I said this does not fix the issue. I did tried all I can find on stack overflow

Comment: ok, just found a solution. If I add the definition to those libraries directly to bower.json and run bower install, with the resolve in place it does install the library with no issue

Answer (score 1):

After some more research and trying I found out a solution and is simple. Instead of running `bower install library -save` I did added the latest versions of the libraries directly to my bower.json and added the resolutions as squiroid said on his answer as follow

```
{
  "name": "Web",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "ignore": [
    "**/.*",
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components",
    "test",
    "tests"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "~3.3.2",
    "jqueryui": "~1.11.2",
    "requirejs": "~2.1.15",
    "fontawesome": "~4.3.0",
    "oclazyload": "~0.5.2",
    "angular": "~1.3.11",
    "angular-route": "~1.3.11",
    "angular-cookies": "~1.3.11",
    "angular-bootstrap": "~0.12.0",
    "angular-local-storage": "~0.1.5",
    "angular-loading-bar": "~0.6.0",
    "angular-smart-table": "~1.4.9",
    "angular-translate": "~2.5.2",
    "angular-translate-loader-static-files": "~2.5.2",
    "angular-translate-storage-cookie": "~2.5.2",
    "angular-translate-storage-local": "~2.5.2",
    "angularjs-toaster": "~0.4.10",
    "angularAMD": "~0.2.1"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "angular": "~1.3.x",
    "angular-cookies": "~1.3.x"
  }
}
```

Then you just run `bower install` and they will be added because are missing.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem but when I run **`bower update`**. It did the trick for me.