# Bower: Cannot find suitable version for Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, bower

this is probably a newbie question, but i do not understand why bower (1.7.9) cannot find a suitable version for Angular when i run:

```
bower install
```

or when it cannot find a suitable version for Angular-translate when i run:

```
bower update
```

(Why does it even give me a different error when i run either command in the above?)

I have updated every package to their latest versions and I did not find any package which would require an older version of Angular. Here is my bower.json:

```js
{
  "name": "test",
  "homepage": "http://www.google.nl",
  "version": "0.2.1",
  "ignore": [
    ".jshintrc",
    "**/*.txt"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "1.5.9",
    "angular-animate": "1.6.0-rc.2",
    "angular-bootstrap": "2.3.0",
    "angular-cookies": "1.6.0-rc.2",
    "angular-hotkeys": "0.2.2",
    "angular-i18n": "1.6.0-rc.2",
    "angular-route": "1.6.0-rc.2",
    "angular-translate": "2.13.1",
    "angular-sanitize": "1.6.0-rc.2",
    "angular-translate-loader-static-files": "2.8.1",
    "angular-ui-bootstrap-datetimepicker": "2.0.3",
    "angular-loading-bar": "0.9.0",
    "jquery": "3.1.1",
    "moment": "2.17.1",
    "ng-dialog": "0.6.4",
    "ng-focus-if": "1.0.7",
    "ng-tags-input": "3.1.1",
    "ngInfiniteScroll": "https://github.com/hlsolutions/ngInfiniteScroll.git#scroll-on-any-lement",
    "angular-ui-select": "0.19.6",
    "placeholders": "https://github.com/jamesallardice/Placeholders.js.git#~4.0.1",
    "angular-atomic-notify": "~1.0.3",
    "underscore": "https://github.com/components/underscore.git#~1.8.3",
    "angulartics-google-analytics": "0.4.0",
    "angular-ui-tinymce": "~0.0.17",
    "angular-collection": "~0.5.2",
    "angular-mocks": "1.6.0-rc.2",
    "angular-translate-handler-log": "2.13.1"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem I see is related to:

```
"angular-translate": "2.13.1",
...
"angular-translate-loader-static-files": "2.8.1",
```

The problem is:
- you are requesting exact versions
- angular-translate-loader-static-files also requests angular-translate, but it demands the same version (2.8.1)
- bower does not allow multiple version of the same library

One solution would be:
 "angular-translate-loader-static-files": "2.13.1"

The same problem is with angular, you should use "angular": "1.6.0-rc.2" since you already request this version for other modules that depend on angular.

However, this is not necessarily the best way to go, because for example I see you are using some libraries that want angular < 1.6 (ngInfiniteScroll) so you will not be able to make these work in your project if you really want to use the 1.6 version.

A better idea would be to require version more loosely (e.g. "angular": ">=1.5.x"), then let bower find the most suitable version for all your dependencies - but this will most likely require you to work with older versions or risk incompatibility issues.

Answer (score 1):

It often happens when you already have an old version of a library (here it's angular) downloaded in your bower_components of your project.

Generally to fix this, i just empty my bower_components before redo a bower install and everything get back to the normal.

Hope this will help in your case.

Answer (score 0):

See if the final answer to a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28196525/bower-error-unable-to-find-suitable-version-for-angular?rq=1) helps

"Instead of running bower install library -save I did added the latest versions of the libraries directly to my bower.json and added the resolutions..."

Comment: I did just that in my example above, but this did not resolve my issue