# bower install error for angular

Tags: angularjs, bower

I am getting error while trying to install bower.

Here is the log:

I have checked other post with similar error but it has not worked.

> ```
> $ bower install
> bower bootstrap#^3.2.0          cached https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap.git#3.3.7
> bower bootstrap#^3.2.0        validate 3.3.7 against https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap.git#^3.2.0
> bower angular-resource#^1.4.0   cached https://github.com/angular/bower-angular-resource.git#1.6.0
> bower angular-resource#^1.4.0 validate 1.6.0 against https://github.com/angular/bower-angular-resource.git#^1.4.0
> bower angular-animate#^1.4.0    cached https://github.com/angular/bower-angular-animate.git#1.6.0
> bower angular-animate#^1.4.0  validate 1.6.0 against https://github.com/angular/bower-angular-animate.git#^1.4.0
> bower angular#^1.4.0            cached https://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1.6.0
> bower angular#^1.4.0          validate 1.6.0 against https://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#^1.4.0
> bower angular-route#^1.4.0      cached https://github.com/angular/bower-angular-route.git#1.6.0
> bower angular-route#^1.4.0    validate 1.6.0 against https://github.com/angular/bower-angular-route.git#^1.4.0
> bower angular-cookies#^1.4.0    cached https://github.com/angular/bower-angular-cookies.git#1.6.0
> bower angular-cookies#^1.4.0  validate 1.6.0 against https://github.com/angular/bower-angular-cookies.git#^1.4.0
> bower angular-sanitize#^1.4.0   cached https://github.com/angular/bower-angular-sanitize.git#1.6.0
> bower angular-sanitize#^1.4.0 validate 1.6.0 against https://github.com/angular/bower-angular-sanitize.git#^1.4.0
> bower angular-touch#^1.4.0      cached https://github.com/angular/bower-angular-touch.git#1.6.0
> bower angular-touch#^1.4.0    validate 1.6.0 against https://github.com/angular/bower-angular-touch.git#^1.4.0
> bower bootstrap-treeview#^1.2.0 cached https://github.com/jonmiles/bootstrap-treeview.git#1.2.0
> bower bootstrap-treeview#^1.2.0         validate 1.2.0 against https://github.com/jonmiles/bootstrap-treeview.git#^1.2.0
> bower angular-ivh-treeview#^1.0.4         cached https://github.com/ivantage/angular-ivh-treeview.git#1.0.4
> bower angular-ivh-treeview#^1.0.4       validate 1.0.4 against https://github.com/ivantage/angular-ivh-treeview.git#^1.0.4
> bower angular-mocks#^1.4.0                cached https://github.com/angular/bower-angular-mocks.git#1.6.0
> bower angular-mocks#^1.4.0              validate 1.6.0 against https://github.com/angular/bower-angular-mocks.git#^1.4.0
> bower angular-material#^1.1.1             cached https://github.com/angular/bower-material.git#1.1.1
> bower angular-material#^1.1.1           validate 1.1.1 against https://github.com/angular/bower-material.git#^1.1.1
> bower jquery#1.9.1 - 3                    cached https://github.com/jquery/jquery-dist.git#3.1.1
> bower jquery#1.9.1 - 3                  validate 3.1.1 against https://github.com/jquery/jquery-dist.git#1.9.1 - 3
> bower jquery#>= 1.9.0                     cached https://github.com/jquery/jquery-dist.git#3.1.1
> bower jquery#>= 1.9.0                   validate 3.1.1 against https://github.com/jquery/jquery-dist.git#>= 1.9.0
> bower angular#~1.2.18 || ~1.4.0 || ~1.5.0 cached https://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1.5.9
> bower angular#~1.2.18 || ~1.4.0 || ~1.5.0         validate 1.5.9 against https://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#~1.2.18 || ~1.4.0 || ~1.5.0
> bower angular-aria#^1.4.8                           cached https://github.com/angular/bower-angular-aria.git#1.6.0
> bower angular-aria#^1.4.8                         validate 1.6.0 against https://github.com/angular/bower-angular-aria.git#^1.4.8
> bower angular-messages#^1.4.8                       cached https://github.com/angular/bower-angular-messages.git#1.6.0
> bower angular-messages#^1.4.8                     validate 1.6.0 against https://github.com/angular/bower-angular-messages.git#^1.4.8
> bower                                            ECONFLICT Unable to find suitable version for angular
> ```

Comment: Since you don't say what other posts you've looked at, here are the potential duplicates I can see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18922511/strange-angular-version-resolving-bug-with-bower-install?rq=1, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25915729/unable-to-find-a-suitable-version-for-angular-bower-install?rq=1

Comment: See: https://github.com/bower/bower/issues/866

Comment: could you please share your `bower.json`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

`bower install angular --force-latest`